# Use AutoMapper to flatten object to int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following Map in AutoMapper:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<MySourceObject, Int32>()
    .ForMember(d => d, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id));
```

I am trying to map the `Id` property of the source object to just an `int` as the destination.

Unfortunately, the above gives the following error:

```
Custom configuration for members is only supported for
              top-level individual members on a type
```

Any ideas?

What I am trying to achieve is not having to pass an entire complex object through to the ViewModel when all I need is the `Id` to bind to a `DropDownList`, as the returning POSTed form won't recreate the complex object, just return the int.  An `int` is all I need :)

Now, I could do this myself in code, but then that diminishes the point of having automapper.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MySourceObject, int>().ConstructUsing(source => source.Id);
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed :)  Solution presented and tested, and yet SO wont let me accept it as the accepted answer yet :(  Sometimes limits just ... limit you unduly.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Pound It, Noggin!